# XSLT Conditional Lookup Table

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two lookup tables in my XSLT.

Table A:

```
<manufacturerA:lookup>
  <device code="129" mapped="foo device"/>
</manufacturerA:lookup>
```

Table B:

```
<manufacturerB:lookup>
  <device code="129" mapped="bar device"/>
</manufacturerB:lookup>
```

Is it possible to conditionally assign a lookup table to a variable based on a passed in parameter `protocol`?
I have tried this to no avail:

```
<xsl:template match="device">
  <xsl:param name="protocol"/>
  <xsl:variable name="devtype" select="type"/>
  <xsl:variable name="devlookup">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$protocol=1">
        <xsl:text>document('')/xsl:stylesheet/manufacturerA:lookup/device</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$protocol=2">
        <xsl:text>document('')/xsl:stylesheet/manufacturerB:lookup/device</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  ...

  <!-- use the lookup to find textual description -->
  <xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:value-of select="$devlookup[@code=$devtype]/@mapped"/>
  </xsl:attribute>

</xsl:template>
```

**Desired outcome**

If I convert source XML...

```
<blob>
  <protocol>1</protocol>
  <device>
    <type>129</type>
  </device>
</blob>
<blob>
  <protocol>2</protocol>
  <device>
    <type>129</type>
  </device>
</blob>
```

It should convert to "foo device" and "bar device" respectively.

**Note:**

The source XML is from a customer and its format is therefore etched in stone for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:variable name="devlookup" select="document('')[$protocol=1]/xsl:stylesheet/manufacturerA:lookup/device | document('')[$protocol=2]/xsl:stylesheet/manufacturerB:lookup/device"/>`.

Comment: You beauty! I wouldn't call it simple, but a lot simpler than my best effort. Thanks.

Comment: Alas, I could not use your solution. This conditional assignment struct is not supported in Qt4, so I resorted to using two lookup variables and a `choose... when` on which one to use for my `xsl:value-of`. It is still a good answer though. Just adding this information for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the lookup table, I take mine in as a parameter.  Consider the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:param name="tablename">xxxx</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document($tablename)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="$lookupDoc/root/tag1/etc/etc/etc"/></value>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When calling it, I simply pass the lookup table as follows:

```
xsltproc --stringparam tablename file2.xml tableparam.xsl 1639089.xml
```

Please keep in mind that your lookup tables should all have the same schema.

Comment: My tables and templates are in one monolithic XSLT document for the simple reason that the source XML can have mixed protocol.
Doesn't mean your answer is wrong, just means your answer wouldn't have worked for my problem.